# How can I present inside a tab of a UITabBarViewController?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to be able to create a TabBarViewController with some tabs and then push into the given tabs

```
let tabBarViewController = UITabBarController()
let redVc = UIViewController()
redVc.view.backgroundColor = .red

let blueVc = UIViewController()
blueVc.view.backgroundColor = .blue

tabBarViewController.viewControllers = [redVc, blueVc]
```

This created a tabBarViewController with a red and a blue tab. Now I want to push a yellow VC to the red tab so that I have a yellow and a blue tab.

```
let yellowVc = UIViewController()
yellowVc.view.backgroundColor = .yellow


tabBarViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

// this doesn't work
viewController.present(tabBarViewController, animated: true)

// must use this
tabBarViewController.viewControllers![0] = yellowVc
```

What should I do to be able to present in a given tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your UITabbarController in such a way, that each of it's child is a UINavigationController.

All together, you then have the following hierarchy:

- `UITabbarController`

  - child1 (`UINavigationController`)

    - first content ViewController
  - child2 (`UINavigationController`)

    - second content ViewController

Now from within each contentViewController, you can use `navigationcontroller.push` to push a new viewController to the stack and it will stay inside the tabbar.

Comment: thanks, will check that out. any idea why my attempt is failing?